# java hibernate - unneeded saving of a method return value because it starts with get..()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a

```
String getDisplayString();
```

method in a class which is a hibernate entity. 
When I run the code there is an exception that tells me that I have to have a

```
setDisplayString()
```

Though there is no Member called DisplayString. No, to solve it quickly I havve created a set method that does nothing. it runs - but it saves a culmumn named DisplayString with the result of the getDisplayString() method (though not a member).

How do I make a getDisplayString() method and let Hibernate not use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If class is mapped with annotations, you need to mark your get method as `@Transient`.